# Окончание во множественном числе

Tags: окончания

От чего зависит изменение окончания существительных во множественном числе?

- окно - окна
- дерево - деревья
- стул - стулья
- книга - книги
- оса - осы
- пчела - пчёлы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 От чего зависит изменение окончания существительных
во множественном числе?
```

От склонения, конечно.

Большое число окончаний связано с историей развития системы склонений русских существительных.

1. В настоящее время среди сущ. муж. рода второго склонения наиболее распространены два окончания: -ы/-и и -а/-я, причём в разговорной речи и просторечии особой продуктивностью отмечено окончание -а/-я. Оно частично вытесняет окончание -ы/-и и в литературном языке.
   Так, в XIX веке распространены были формы до́мы, по́езды, а в ХХ веке – дома́, поезда́. Уже в последние десятилетия формы дире́кторы, профе́ссоры стали устаревшими, а их место заняли варианты директора́, профессора́.
   Однако процесс вытеснения окончания -ы/-и окончанием -а/-я в литературном языке идёт значительно медленнее, чем в просторечии именно потому, что формы с -а/-я во многом воспринимаются как второсортные, сниженные.

Использование того и другого окончания определяется рядом факторов:

а) окончание -а/-я имеют существительные, обозначающие парные понятия:
глаза́, рукава́, обшлага́;

б) большинство односложных слов имеет во множественном числе окончание -ы/-и (торты, флоты, шумы), но возможны и исключения (дома́, сорта́);

в) окончание -а/-я, как правило, имеют во множественном числе двусложные слова с ударением на первый слог.
Ср.: ка́тер – катера́, шо́мпол – шомпола́.
Если ударение в начальной форме падает на второй слог, то во множественном числе распространено окончание -ы/-и: арбу́з – арбу́зы;

г) в трёхсложных и многосложных словах распространено окончание -ы/-и с ударением на середине слова: апте́кари, догово́ры (форма договора́ хотя и допустима, но всё же нежелательна!);

д) иноязычные слова (чаще французского происхождения) с финалью -ёр/-ер и ударением на последний слог обычно имеют окончание -ы/-и:
офице́р – офице́ры, киоскёр – киоскёры, шофёр – шофёры (!);

е) слова латинского происхождения с финалью -тор/-сор обычно имеют окончание -ы/-и (компью́теры, проце́ссоры), хотя у одушевлённых существительных, достаточно частотных и употребительных в речи, распространённым становится окончание -а/-я.
Ср.: коммента́торы, ле́кторы, нова́торы – директора́, доктора́, профессора́;

ж) окончание -а/-я обычно имеют двусложные и трёхсложные существительные с ударением на первом слоге и с финалью -л/-льи -р/-рь:
ки́вер – кивера́, ки́тель – кителя́ (допустимо – ки́тели).
Иногда одно и то же существительное одновременно подпадает под действие нескольких взаимоисключающих факторов. Именно среди таких слов наблюдается наибольшее число вариантов в речи.

Например, слова фа́ктор, ве́ктор двусложные с ударением на первом слоге, поэтому во множественном числе они могли бы иметь окончание -а/-я. В то же время это неодушевлённые существительные латинского происхождения с финалью -тор, поэтому они могут иметь окончание -ы/-и. В литературном языке побеждает действие второго фактора и нормативными являются варианты ве́кторы, фа́кторы.

Существительное бу́нкер двусложное с ударением на первый слог, поэтому может иметь окончание -а. Но как слово немецкого, а не французского происхождения на -ер, оно может иметь окончание -ы. В литературном языке равноправны обе формы:бункера́ и бу́нкеры.

Иногда использование того или иного окончания определяется значением и сочетаемостью слова:

•   борова́ (горизонтальные части дымоходов) и бо́ровы (кастрированные самцы свиньи);

•   кондуктора́/конду́кторы трамваев и конду́кторы в станке (специальные приспособления в механизмах);

•   корпуса́ завода, кадетские корпуса́ и ко́рпусы человека или животного;

•   меха́ (выделанные шкуры животных) и кузнечные ме́хи;

•   о́бразы в романе и образа́ святых в церкви;

2. Сущ. среднего рода второго склонения в основном имеют во множественном числе окончание -а/-я: кольцо́ – ко́льца, крыльцо́ – кры́льца.

•   Это окончание (в отличие от существительных мужского рода) обычно бывает безударным: сёла, стёкла, вёдра.

•   В начальной форме ударение обычно падает на последний слог: село́, стекло́, ведро́.

•   Но возможно и ударное окончание -а/-я – зеркала́ (в начальной форме такие существительные обычно имеют ударение на основе – зе́ркало).

•   Значительно реже существительные среднего рода имеют окончание -ы/-и: плечо́ – пле́чи.

Целый ряд существительных характеризуется нестандартным образованием формы именительного падежа множественного числа:

•   существительные мужского рода на -ёнок во множественном числе имеют суффикс -ят- и безударное окончание -а:
жеребёнок – жеребята, ребёнок – ребята;

•   существительные на -анин/-янин во множественном числе оканчиваются на -ане/-яне:

гражданин – граждане, крестьянин – крестьяне, армянин – армяне (!);

Обратите внимание на формы множественного числа существительных: хозя́ин – хозя́ева (очень грубая ошибка – хозяева́!), дно – до́нья, ши́ло – ши́лья, ку́рица – ку́ры, су́дно – суда́, ребёнок – дети, человек – люди.

Comment: Ужас. Как же всё это сложно. Не представляю, как это всё иностранцы изучают.

Comment: Если задумываться, а если нет - язык сам выбирает, при затруднении  - в словарь, и всё нормально.

Comment: Ну нам Русским то проще, мы интуитивно чувствуем.

Answer (score 1):

Окно ― окна ― окон,  дерево ― деревья ― деревьев, стул ― стулья ― стульев,
книга ― книги ― книг, оса ― осы ― ос, пчела ― пчёлы ― пчёл.

**Грамматика**

1) В трех падежах мн.числа:  дательном, творительном и предложном – сущ.  имеют одинаковые  окончания: АМ/ЯМ, АМИ/ЯМИ, АХ/ЯХ.

2) В И.п и Р.п. существительные могут иметь два вида окончаний в И.п. (**Ы/И и А/Я**) и три вида окончаний в Р.п. (**ОВ/ЕВ, ЕЙ и нулевое**).

3) Существительные имеют следующие **основные** окончания:
1-е скл.: **стЕны, зЕмли** – окончание Ы/И в И.п., **стен, земель** – нулевое окончание в Р.п. 
2-е  скл., м. род: **столы, жители** – окончание Ы/И в И.п., **столов, жителей, листьев** – окончание ОВ (твердый вариант) и окончания ЕЙ и ЕВ (мягкий вариант)  в Р.п.
2-е скл., ср. род:  **окна, поля** – окончание А/Я в И.п., **окон, полей** ―   нулевое окончание и окончание ЕЙ  в Р.п. 
3-ье  скл.: **пЕчи** – окончание И в И.п., **печЕй** – окончание ЕЙ в Р.п.

4)  Обратим внимание **на следующую закономерность**: если в начальной форме слово имеет  ненулевое окончание (**стена, окно**), то в Р.п. окончание нулевое (**стен, окон**), и наоборот, при нулевом окончании в начальной форме (**стол**) наблюдается ненулевое окончание ОВ в Р.п.  (**столов**).

4) Кроме **основных** окончаний, существительные во множественном числе могут иметь **вариантные** окончания, например: **дом – дома, снег – снега, город – города – берег – берега** – в этих примерах окончание А в И.п. является вариантным для существительных м. рода (основное окончание Ы/И);  **яблоко – яблоки** – окончание И в И.п. является вариантным  для существительных среднего рода (основное окончание А/Я).

5) Основные проблемы возникают при выборе **основных и вариантных**  окончаний **для  сущ. м.р**.: а) лагери и лагеря, штормы и шторма, договоры и договора **(И.п.);** б) осетин/черкесов, чулок/носков, гусар/гусаров, грамм/граммов **(Р.п.)**