# Окончание во множественном числе у существительных

Tags: морфология

Я знаю, что проблемы с окончаниями множественного числа в русском связаны с несуществующим ныне двойственным числом. Однако всё же есть ли какое-то объяснение, которое позволит стройно расположить существительные так, чтобы было легко с ходу определить, какая форма является правильной (`ы`/`а`, `ов`/`нулевое окончание`)?

---

P.S. прерогатива данного вопроса - подготовка к ЕГЭ, так что интересует в первую очередь ответ для "жертвы ЕГЭ", а потом уж как для обывателя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я скопирую свой ответ на эту тему, а часть материала (по Р.п.) добавлю.[Окончание во множественном числе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428628/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5)

Грамматика

1) В трех падежах мн.числа: дательном, творительном и предложном – сущ. имеют одинаковые окончания: АМ/ЯМ, АМИ/ЯМИ, АХ/ЯХ.

2) В И.п и Р.п. существительные могут иметь два вида окончаний в И.п. (Ы/И и А/Я) и **три вида окончаний в Р.п. (ОВ/ЕВ, ЕЙ и нулевое).**

3) Существительные имеют следующие **основные** окончания:

1-е скл.: стЕны, зЕмли – окончание Ы/И в И.п., **стен, земель – нулевое окончание в Р.п.**

2-е скл., м. род: столы, жители – окончание Ы/И в И.п., столов, жителей, листьев – **окончание ОВ (твердый вариант) и окончания ЕЙ и ЕВ (мягкий вариант) в Р.п.**
2-е скл., ср. род: окна, поля – окончание А/Я в И.п., окон, полей ― нулевое окончание и окончание ЕЙ в Р.п.

3-ье скл.: пЕчи – окончание И в И.п., печЕй – окончание ЕЙ в Р.п.

4) Обратим внимание **на следующую закономерность**: если в начальной форме слово имеет ненулевое окончание (стена, окно), то в Р.п. окончание нулевое (стен, окон), и наоборот, при нулевом окончании в начальной форме (стол) наблюдается ненулевое окончание ОВ в Р.п. (столов).

4) Кроме основных окончаний, существительные во множественном числе могут иметь **вариантные окончания,** например: дом – дома, снег – снега, город – города – берег – берега – в этих примерах окончание А в И.п. является вариантным для существительных м. рода (основное окончание Ы/И); яблоко – яблоки – окончание И в И.п. является вариантным для существительных среднего рода (основное окончание А/Я).

5) Основные проблемы возникают при выборе основных и вариантных окончаний для сущ. м.р.: а) лагери и лагеря, штормы и шторма, договоры и договора (И.п.); б) осетин/черкесов, чулок/носков, гусар/гусаров, грамм/граммов (Р.п.)

**Существительные м.р.** с вариантными окончаниями в Р.п. можно разделить НА 5 ГРУПП:

Группа 1. **Названия лиц по социальной, национальной, территориальной принадлежности** 
А) Вариантное нулевое окончание в Р. п. мн. числа имеют следующие существительные: турок, грузин, цыган, но: арабов, киргизов – основное окончание ОВ.

Б) Нулевое окончание имеют также существительные с суффиксом АНИН/ЯНИН (англичанин – англичане - англичан), а также некоторые  существительные  с изменяющейся основой (боярин – бояре – бояр).

Группа 2. **Парные предметы**

А) Вариантное нулевое окончание в Р. п. мн. числа имеют существительные, обозначающие парные предметы: пара ботинок, чулок, погон, но: пара носков – основное окончание ОВ:

Б) Для существительного рельс предпочтительной является форма ***рельсов*** с основным окончанием ОВ, хотя в разговорной речи встречается форма рельс, соответствующая устаревшей начальной форме  слова – рельса (эта форма раньше относилась к женскому роду).

Группа 3.  **Воинские подразделения**

А) Вариантное нулевое окончание используется в существительных, обозначающих старые воинские части при СОБИРАТЕЛЬНОМ значении существительного (отряд гусар).

Б) Основное окончание ОВ пишется при обозначении ОТДЕЛЬНЫХ ЛИЦ, в том числе в сочетаниях с ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНЫМИ (пять гусаров),  а также в существительных, обозначающих современные  воинские части (группа саперов).

Группа 4. **Название единиц измерения**

А) Вариантное нулевое окончание употребляется в сочетании слов ампер, ватт, вольт, герц, рентген с числительными.

Б) Слова гектар, грамм, килограмм, Ом  имеют книжную форму с окончанием ОВ и разговорную форму с нулевым окончанием.

Группа 5. **Название овощей и плодов**
  А) В этом случае нет вариантных окончаний, но используются РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ ОСНОВНЫЕ окончания для существительных разных склонений и родов:

килограмм яблок, груш, слив – основное нулевое окончание в сущ. ж.р. и ср.р., но: килограмм апельсинов, помидоров, баклажанов – основное окончание ОВ  существительных м.р.

Б) Встречающиеся  в разговорной речи варианты с нулевым окончанием существительных м.р. не являются нормативными, то есть не допускаются выражения: килограмм абрикос, мандарин, помидор.

Материал взят из Грамматики-80.

Answer (score 0):

> Я знаю, что проблемы с окончаниями множественного числа в русском
>   связаны с несуществующим ныне двойственным числом.

Интересно. Я вот не знаю никаких сложностей с окончаниями множественного числа. О чем речь вообще? Вы не могли бы изложить проблемы "жертв ЕГЭ" более подробно?

В отношении двойственного числа. Единственный более или менее актуальный его рудимент - формы для парных предметов (**глаза, рога**), проявляющиеся, правда, не очень последовательно. Но сложностей они не представляют. Даже на уровне ЕГЭ.

Еще некоторое влияние двойственного можно усмотреть в формах "родительного падежа" при числительных два, три четыре (***два, три, четыре сапога, часа, яблока, две машины - но пять сапогов, яблок, машин***). Однако тут связь именно с двойственным числом весьма дискуссионна даже для филологов, а сложностей эти формы тем более не вызывают.

Так в чем вопрос-то?

> Однако, всё же, есть ли какое-то объяснение, которое позволит стройно
>   расположить существительные так, чтобы было легко сходу определить,
>   какая форма является правильной? (ы/а, ов/нулевое окончание)

Искать объяснения, загоняющие языковые процессы в Прокрустово ложе предопределенных схем, занятие заведомо неблагодарное.
Есть некие закономерности, но они не универсальны.
Думаю, что вы о них прекрасно осведомлены.
Окончания на -а/-я в именительном множественно принимают главным образом существительные среднего рода и мужского рода - преимущественно с безударными суффиксами -ель и -ер/-ор. (Учителя, доктора, катера). Особенно это касается названий профессий. Для существительных женского рода такое невозможно.

В отношении родительного множественного примерно та же картина.
окончание -ов как правило имеют существительные мужского рода, нулевое - среднего и женского, и ряд существительных мужского, в том числе некоторые, обозначающие парные предметы (глаз) и обозначающие группы одушевленных существ с оттенком собирательности (солдат, зверят). Окончания на -ей принимают существительные женского и изредка мужского рода, имеющие мягкую основу (мышей, дочерей, червей, гвоздей, зверей) и слово дети (детей).

Существительные, не имеющие единственного числа, зачастую имеют вообще ничем не мотивированные формы - кроме исторических процессов, разумеется: ***очки-очков, часы-часов, ворота-ворот, сани-саней, ножницы-ножниц.***

Все сложные случаи всегда проверяются по словарю. То, что в соответствующих словарях эти формы приводятся, как раз и говорит о том, что какого-то единого "правила" на все случаи нет.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Эх, поспешили вы с правкой. Я её убил не по причине того, что не согласен, а потому, что добавил большой кусок. Но если вам не лень, можете отредактировать повторно.

Comment: Ничего, окончание правильное оставили, а остальное — внешний вид.