# Принцип формирования окончания у существительных во множественном числе

Tags: окончания, морфемика, множественное-число

У слова дом, множественное число дома, а не домы. Но это очевидно какое-то исключение.
Например, у слов сом, лом, двор, вор, бор - множественное оканчивается на -Ы-.

1. Приведите список всех слов-исключений, когда множественное оканчивается на -А- вместо -Ы-
2. Почему эти исключения сформировались?
3. А может это не исключение? Много же слов типа город-городА итд. Почему тогда дом-домА исключение?

Далее надо понять почему одинакового вида слова имеют разные окончания в множественном числе:

```
ком - комы, комья
клин - клинья, а не клины.
блин - блины, а не блинья
сом - сомы, а не сомья
```

4. Что из этого исключения, а что правило и на каком основании произошло разделение по окончаниям?

В принципе на первые 3 вопроса ответ примерно был дан [Окончание во множественном числе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428628). Остается 4-ый вопрос - по какому принципу в одних случаях корень приобретает мягкий знак во множественном числе, а в других - остается неизменным?